# Execute text command on a collection

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have a requirement which consists in executing a text command (given by a user) on a collection.

For example this command:

`db.getCollection('MyCollectionName').find({Sig : {$lt: 0}})` (executed in Robo3T) should be executed in C# and the results must be sent back.

The user would send me the collection name and then the "find" part (I guess).

Security is not a concern in this case (client is warned, we'll use a readonly user and grant access to the collection depending on roles in another DB)

How can I do that ?  Ideally I'd like to provide a method like this one:
`ExecuteStringCommand(string collection, string command)`
and compose the query to be executed on the collection, but it seems that I can't execute a query directly on the collection (using `GetCollection`).
The only place I can use a command is directly on the database level, but I don't know a way to select the collection from the query itself.

Is there a way to do this ?  I'm using MongoDB driver version 2.4.4

Thanks

Comment: Is it only `find`, or any other [collection command](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/js-collection/) e.g. aggregate, explain etc?

Comment: I guess they'll need all king of readonly commands, like aggregate indeed

Comment: Then I reckon `runCommand` would be the best option.

Comment: Could you give me an example with `runCommand` please ?

Comment: Could you show a teeny tiny research effort? Docs: http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.4/apidocs/html/Overload_MongoDB_Driver_MongoDatabase_RunCommand.htm, Examples:
https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-1514 with comments.

Comment: Yes I meant I understand how to run a command, that's not the point, my problem is that I don't understand how you can select the collection in the query, all I did until now was using the javascript syntax, and it doesn't seem to be working with runCommand.  But thanks anyway

Comment: Okay, I must admit the documentation lacks examples. runCommand is executed on db level. Collection name is part of the command itself, if the command requires it at all. E.g. for `find` https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/find/#dbcmd.find collection name is the value of "find" property of the json.

Comment: Thanks @AlexBlex, it works using this method.  Is there a name to refer to this syntax ?  As opposed to the other syntax I used before (db.collection.find() ).  Just to be able to tell my client he'll need to use this syntax.

Comment: hmmm, a "command json", "mongodb command"? Never though about how to refer to a command apart from "command" =). The syntax is the same - json.

Answer (score 0):

You could shell out to mongo.exe.

```
mongo databasename --eval "db.collectionname.find()"
```